# Displaying Numbers from onClickListener() Method

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener

I'm looking to display a string of numbers from button clicks in the same `TextView` field. So far, I'm only able to display one at a time with each press. How can I display all the numbers I click on the same line? My code looks like the following:

```
   one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Display.setText("1");

       }
   });
   two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Display.setText("2");

       }
   });
   .
   .
   .
   nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Display.setText("9");

       }
   });
   zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Display.setText("0");

       }
   });
```

How can I get it to where if I press buttons one through three my display will show "123" instead of "1" then "2" then "3" individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a string variable containing the current numbers being displayed, then append each digit when the button is clicked, and display that.

```
 String digits = "";
 one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          digits += "1";
          Display.setText(digits);
       }
   });
   two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           digits += "2";
           Display.setText(digits);
       }
   });
```